# How to display a byte array as hex values

Tags: python

```
>>> struct.pack('2I',12, 30)
b'\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00'    
>>> struct.pack('2I',12, 31)
b'\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x00\x00\x00'
>>> struct.pack('2I',12, 32)
b'\x0c\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00'
                  ^in question
>>> struct.pack('2I',12, 33)
b'\x0c\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x00'
                  ^in question
```

I'd like all values to display as hex

Comment: `' ' === '\x20'`, `'!' === '\x21'`

Comment: I know but how can I get it display as a hex number, so everything is uniform?

Comment: Do you mean, in the interactive console? I'd say it makes everything to not use hex codes, as strings are not supposed to hold unprintable characters, so you'd need to format them as hex codes manually; but then they'll show with double backslashes in the console.

Comment: Im writing code to create a special packet, and for debug purposes I want to see where things are getting packed so I'm printing it out. I could use print from my code

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about his?

```
>>> data = struct.pack('2I',12, 30)
>>> [hex(ord(c)) for c in data]
['0xc', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x1e', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0']
```

The expression `[item for item in sequence]` is a so called [**list comprehension**](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It's basically a very compact way of writing a simple `for` loop, and creating a list from the result.

The [`ord()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) builtin function takes a string, and turns it into an integer that's its corresponding unicode code point (for characters in the ASCII character set that's the same as their value in the ASCII table).

Its counterpart, [`chr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) for 8bit strings or [`unichr()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr) for unicode objects do the opposite.

The [`hex()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hex) builtin then simply converts the integers into their hex representation.

---

As pointed out by @TimPeters, in Python 3 you would need to lose the `ord()`, because iterating over a bytes object will (already) yield integers:

```
Python 3.4.0a3 (default, Nov  8 2013, 18:33:56)
>>> import struct
>>> data = struct.pack('2I',12, 30)
>>> type(data)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> type(data[1])
<class 'int'>
>>>
>>> [hex(i) for i in data]
['0xc', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x1e', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0']
```

Comment: Note: in Python3, you have to lose the `ord()` - iterating over a `bytes` object gives integers.

Comment: I like this answer, but could you explain how this is working please? what do the brackets do?

Comment: @TimPeters thank you, going to update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 16):

See `bytes.hex()`:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('2I',12,30).hex()   # available since Python 3.5
'0c0000001e000000'
>>> struct.pack('2I',12,30).hex(' ')  # separator available since Python 3.8
'0c 00 00 00 1e 00 00 00'
>>> struct.pack('2I',12,30).hex(' ',4) # bytes_per_sep also since Python 3.8
'0c000000 1e000000'
```

Older Python use `binascii.hexlify`:

```
>>> import binascii
>>> import struct
>>> binascii.hexlify(struct.pack('2I',12,30))
b'0c0000001e000000'
```

Or if you want spaces to make it more readable:

```
>>> ' '.join(format(n,'02X') for n in struct.pack('2I',12,33))
'0C 00 00 00 21 00 00 00'
```

Python 3.6+, using f-strings (but `.hex()` is available and easier).

```
>>> ' '.join(f'{n:02X}' for n in struct.pack('2I',12,33))
'0C 00 00 00 21 00 00 00'
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to reformat it yourself if you want `\x` escapes everywhere; e.g.,

```
>>> import struct
>>> r = struct.pack('2I',12, 33)
>>> r
b'\x0c\x00\x00\x00!\x00\x00\x00'
>>> list(r)
[12, 0, 0, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0]
>>> print("".join("\\x%02x" % i for i in r))
\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x21\x00\x00\x00
```

Comment: Given the desired usage, I guess joining just the hexes with spaces will do

Comment: @JanDvorak, if that's what the OP wants, it's trivial to change this to do that.  I'm just answering the question they asked ;-)

Comment: If we're printing it, then this will do nicely: `print(*(r'\x%02x' % b for b in r), sep='')`

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3.7, `bytes` objects don't have an `encode()` method; the following code doesn't work anymore.

```py
import struct

hex_str = struct.pack('2I',12, 30).encode('hex')
```

Instead of `encode()`, Python 3.7 code should use the [`hex()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.hex) method, introduced in Python 3.5.

```py
import struct

# hex_str will contain the '0c0000001e000000' string.
hex_str = struct.pack('2I',12, 30).hex()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to convert byte array to hex string with `encode`. It works for any Python from Python 2.4:

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Oct 10 2016, 12:50:22)
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('2I',12, 30).encode('hex')
'0c0000001e000000'
>>> struct.pack('2I',12, 31).encode('hex')
'0c0000001f000000'
>>> struct.pack('2I',12, 32).encode('hex')
'0c00000020000000'
>>> struct.pack('2I',12, 33).encode('hex')
'0c00000021000000'
```